# How to use * whilst using self in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use `*` with `self`

here is my choices code:

```
self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*- to sign.jpg"))
```

and here is my dropdown OptionsMenu Code:

```
self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, self.*choices, command = func)
```

when I remove `self` from both choices, it works fine. But with `self` it does not work, this is my error:

```
   self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, self.*choices, command = func)
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**here is working code:**

```
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*- to sign.jpg"))

popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, tkvar, *choices, command = func)
```

**and here is code I tired re-writing:**

```
self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*- to sign.jpg"))

self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, self.*choices, command = func)
self.popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Why is it showing SyntaxError: invalid Syntax as `self.choices`?

Comment: Try `OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, *self.choices, command=func)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it showing SyntaxError: invalid Syntax as self.choices?

Because it is illegal syntax. The `*` goes before a variable name, not somewhere in the middle.

```
OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, *self.choices, command=func)
```

This is called *iterable unpacking*, and is documented here among other places: [Expression lists](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-listshttps://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)